I'm having trouble loading my save file after opening a level
I'm working on save game system and I want to restore the level on load (or open the one from the save game)
The only problem is once I use the open level node the rest of the properties don't get loaded.
I'm sure that the save game object ref is valid and that all the info is intact it's just not setting the properties.
I have tried:

using the open level node at the very end
using a delay right after opening the level



Do you see any difference if you connect the blue Save output pin on the Get node to the nodes that want to read something from the save data?

@DMGregory I just tried it and nothing happend but I pretty sure the save variable is valid
